# Heroku app w/ socket.io refuses connection or sends 404

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, socket.io

After days of trying to figure out what's wrong, I came here to seek help.
My Heroku app is using React as frontend and Socket.io as backend. Here's the drill:
Heroku runs dyno with command "npm run start", which is set to `concurrently 'npm run react' 'npm run server'` to run both front and back ends.

But even if I make it work (can't really even explain how), it only works on my computer. If I try going to the same page on my phone, no requests are made and I can't even tell why, since there is no debug log.

Here is my /src/server/index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const io = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(server)

const port = process.env.PORT || 80

const socketManager = require('./SocketManager') // All functions there

io.on('connection', socketManager);
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../build'))
server.listen(port,() => {
    console.log("Listening on port", port)
})
```

I use config file to dynamically change for the server url.

```
let server = 'https://hidden-waters-73936.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket'; // 404

// let server = window.location.hostname; // 404, same as above
// let server = 'http://localhost:4001'; // works locally on heroku
// let server = '/'; // 404, not found, AND CONNECTION_REFUSED
// let server = 'https://127.0.0.1:4001'; // CONNECTUIN_REFUSED
// let server = 'http://0.0.0.0:4001'; // Doesn't work at all

module.exports = server;
```

Commented out lines are those that I tried. Last try was changing https to ws, as someone recommended earlier, then I tried adding `.com:80/socket.io...`, but still no luck. Every time it's a different Error

Here's what the errors are like with uncommented server variable:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTkYF.jpg

I expect it to make successful requests both on my computer and phone. I'll try my laptop to see the logs and check back if I find anything useful.

**UPDATE for @Ashish

```
React component

import server from '../../config/serverConfig'
const socket = socketIOClient(server);

componentDidMount() {
socket.emit("test", {});
}
```

** EDIT:
My Heroku logs seem to tell me something else is going on:

```
2019-05-13T16:59:55.472135+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [33m[nodemon] 1.19.0[39m
2019-05-13T16:59:55.474073+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [33m[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`[39m
2019-05-13T16:59:55.475362+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [33m[nodemon] watching: *.*[39m
2019-05-13T16:59:55.477060+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [32m[nodemon] starting `node src/server/index.js`[39m
2019-05-13T16:59:56.164302+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Listening on port 40497
2019-05-13T16:59:56.573081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-05-13T16:59:57.538639+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] Something is already running on port 40497.
2019-05-13T16:59:57.585807+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm run react exited with code 0
2019-05-13T17:01:19.780332+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=hidden-waters-73936.herokuapp.com request_id=42a6c345-94b7-441a-afde-82c1e9c52e97 fwd="90.191.14.93" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30004ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Comment: I would suggest to use socket io client api https://socket.io/docs/client-api/. This will fix all of the connection issues.

Comment: @Ashish I am using client in react components to communicate with the server. It's just that Heroku doesn't work as expected

Comment: Can you please post your code where you are making connection?

Comment: In past i had created the app using socket.io. Please check if that helps you. Though it used namespace feature of socket.io, it can help you to figure out solution for you. https://github.com/agabhane/backend-secret-santa https://github.com/agabhane/webapp-secret-santa

Comment: @Ashish Well thanks for some additional info, but I feel like the problem has been solved partly. Client (while using heroku app) gets wrong connection
`polling-xhr.js:269 GET http://127.0.0.1:4001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MgoXuo0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

At least for me it works for now. Here's what I changed:
server config file (AKA what client is listening for)

```
let server = window.location.hostname;

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

if (env === 'development') {
    server = 'http://localhost:4001';
    console.log("Using dev port")
}
module.exports = server;
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install",
    "start": "node src/server/index.js",
    "server": "nodemon src/server/index.js",
    "client": "npm start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "react": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install && npm run build"
```

Heroku procfile:
`web: npm start`

HOWEVER.
I use React Router to navigate through different pages. As soon as a page is refreshed on heroku, it returns "Not found". I suppose it is looking for a .html file with the path name, but I need it to rewrite to index.html like Firebase does.
I tried using create-react-app-buildpack,  with the nginx thing and it seems to crash my server with 
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not Allowed)`
and then changes listening point (I suppose)
`polling-xhr.js:269 POST https://XXXXXXXXXX.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MgpToRX 405 (Not Allowed)`

Is there a way to determine why the problem is occuring? Heroku logs dont seem to tell anything useful.